# Bitbucket pipeline only builds to master

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

In my Bitbucket project repository I have 3 branches

1. master
2. staging
3. development

On my Heroku account I have two apps

1. MyProductionApp
2. MyStagingApp

Both apps are the same, the only difference being I given staging access for demos or to showcase new features before they are implemented in production.

As you can understand, the master branch is suppose to build the MyProductionApp and the staging branch is suppose to deploy the MyStagingApp. The development branch is where active development takes place and it is then merged to staging / master via pull requests.

I have setup bitbucket-pipelines.yml file the following way

```
image: node:6.9.4
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
      - step:
          script: #default script to run
            - echo "This default script will run when something is pushed to this branch"
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Heroku Production Deployment
          deployment: production
          caches:
            - node
          script: #deploy master branch to heroku prod app
            - npm install
            - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_PROD_APP.git HEAD:master
    staging:
      - step:
          name: Heroku Staging Deployment
          deployment: staging
          caches:
            - node
          script: #deploy staging branch to heroku staging app
            - npm install
            - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_STAGING_APP.git HEAD:staging
```

This .yml file is same for all three branches.

The problem is when something is pushed / merged only the master is built. It never builds my staging app.

So if I add a new code and just merge to staging it will run this .yml file but it will only build the master. In the pipeline logs it gives me the following message

> git push
>   https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_STAGING_APP.git
>   HEAD:stagingremote: Pushed to non-master branch, skipping build.

As a result I am unable to showcase new features or bug fixes on the staging app. Any idea why it skips the build on the "non-master" branch? What settings do I need to make to make this happen?

Comment: Did you actually commit and push something in to `staging` branch?